# Can I alias multiple columns? How?

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc and postgres.

Can I alias multiple columns?

Here's the description of my problem:

Data structure:

```
data
id | c1  | c2
-------------
1  | 11  | 12
2  | 21  | 22
```

Notation: c is for column

```
dictionary
id | key | value
----------------
1  | k1  | v11
1  | k2  | v12
2  | k1  | v21
2  | k2  | v22
```

Notation: k is for key, v is for value

You can think of k1 and k2 as two more columns. The data structure is this way because it's constantly changing. I didn't design it, I just have to go with it.

I can't figure out an sql query to give me something like the following (most importantly, for some row, I can access k1 and k2 columns by some name):

```
data
id | c1  | c2  | k1  | k2
-------------------------
1  | 11  | 12  | v11 | v12
2  | 21  | 22  | v21 | v22
```

The problem I keep running into is if I alias the tables, then the sql result will contain two "key" columns from the dictionary table, meaning I can't control which column I access of the two, but if I alias the rows, then I can't control which tables are being referenced inside the sql statement.

The fix I'm thinking is to alias two columns:

```
SELECT * FROM data
FULL JOIN dictionary AS a1,a2,a3
ON data.id = a1
FULL JOIN dictionary AS a4,a5,a6
ON data.id = a4
WHERE a2 = k1 and a5 = k2
```

Notation: a is for alias

The result of this would theoretically look like

```
data
id | c1  | c2  | a3  | a6 
------------------------- 
1  | 11  | 12  | v11 | v12
2  | 21  | 22  | v21 | v22
```

Note all a's would technically be here, but 3 and 6 are the ones I'm interested in

Comment: Did you just make up new syntax, or is that just an alias construct I've never used?

Comment: I think the keyword here is "rollup"; the *shape* (that is, the columns) of the result-set changes in the scenario, right? Generally SQL is *not good* at this, and dynamic (or one-off) queries ensue to get `k0...kN` columns...

Comment: yeah, I was making up syntax to describe the behavior I wanted (which columns I needed to access). Andomar's answer shows the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias the entire table, for example `dictionary as d1`.  Then refer to the column names in that table as `d1.col1`.  For example:

```
SELECT  d.id
,       d.c1
,       d.c2
,       d1.value as a3
,       d2.value as a6
FROM    data as d
LEFT JOIN
        dictionary as d1
ON      data.id = d1.id
        and d1.key = 'k1'
LEFT JOIN
        dictionary as d2
ON      data.id = d2.id
        and d2.key = 'k2'
```

Comment: That would cause one of the two problems I mentioned, wouldn't it? (The resulting table will contain repeating column names.)

Comment: You can alias columns after they are selected, edited in answer.  Kind of surprised you can write a `full join` but not alias columns, hehe :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! I hope this works! I just didn't know how to do multiple aliasing. Is it possible to do something like SELECT *, d1.value as a3, d2.value as a6...  ? Because the actual data is many many columns... Where is documentation on valid syntax of sql? This looks like it should be right but I want to put it against documentation to verify.

Comment: You can use `select d.*` to select all columns from the table aliased as `d`.